# ASP.NET core POST request fail

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a model:

```
public class CoreGoal
{
    [Key]
    public long CoreGoalId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Effect { get; set; }
    public string Target_Audience { get; set; }
    public string Infrastructure { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Benefit> Benefits { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Step> Steps { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubGoal> SubGoals { get; set; }

    public CoreGoal()
    {

    }
 }
```

And Image model is as following:

```
public class Image
{
    [Key]
    public long ImagelId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Base64 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CoreGoalId")]
    public long CoreGoalId { get; set; }

    public Image()
    {

    }
}
```

My controller class:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CoreGoalController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICoreGoalRepository _coreGoalRepository;

    //Controller
    public CoreGoalController(ICoreGoalRepository coreGoalRepository) {
        _coreGoalRepository = coreGoalRepository;
    }

    //Get methods
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<CoreGoal> GetAll()
    {
        return _coreGoalRepository.GetAllCoreGoals();
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetCoreGoal")]
    public IActionResult GetById(long id)
    {
        var item = _coreGoalRepository.Find(id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return new ObjectResult(item);
    }

    //Create
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody] CoreGoal item)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _coreGoalRepository.CreateCoreGoal(item);

        return CreatedAtRoute("GetCoreGoal", new { id = item.CoreGoalId }, item);
    }

}
```

Repository:

```
public class CoreGoalRepository : ICoreGoalRepository
{
    private readonly WebAPIDataContext _db;

    public CoreGoalRepository(WebAPIDataContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    //Add new
    public void CreateCoreGoal(CoreGoal coreGoal)
    {
        _db.CoreGoals.Add(coreGoal);
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }

    //Get all
    public IEnumerable<CoreGoal> GetAllCoreGoals()
    {
        return _db.CoreGoals
            .Include(coreGoal => coreGoal.Benefits)
            .Include(coreGoal => coreGoal.Steps)
            .Include(coreGoal => coreGoal.Images)
            .Include(coreGoal => coreGoal.SubGoals)
            .ToList();
    }

    //Find specific
    public CoreGoal Find(long key)
    {
        return _db.CoreGoals.FirstOrDefault(t => t.CoreGoalId == key);
    }

}

public interface ICoreGoalRepository
{
    void CreateCoreGoal(CoreGoal coreGoal);
    IEnumerable<CoreGoal> GetAllCoreGoals();
    CoreGoal Find(long key);
    void DeleteCoreGoal(long id);
    void UpdateCoreGoal(CoreGoal coreGoal);
}
```

When I do a POST request from swagger I get a template like:

```
{
  "coreGoalId": 0,
  "title": "string",
  "effect": "string",
  "target_Audience": "string",
  "infrastructure": "string",
  "benefits": [
    {
      "benefitId": 0,
      "what": "string",
      "coreGoalId": 0
    }
  ],
  "steps": [
    {
      "stepId": 0,
      "what": "string",
      "coreGoalId": 0
    }
  ],
  "images": [
    {
      "imagelId": 0,
      "base64": "string",
      "coreGoalId": 0
    }
  ],
  "subGoals": [
    {
      "subGoalId": 0,
      "title": "string",
      "priority": "string",
      "audience": "string",
      "social_aspects": "string",
      "coreGoalId": 0,
      "issues": [
        {
          "issueId": 0,
          "title": "string",
          "subGoalID": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

If I POST like like this, my request fails with status 400, however if I remove

```
  "images": [
    {
      "imagelId": 0,
      "base64": "string",
      "coreGoalId": 0
    }
  ],
```

from this request, then it is successful. Why is it happening? All other models i.e. Benefit, Step are exactly identical to Image in structure.

**UPDATE:**
Changing base64 type from byte[] to string eliminates this problem but in that case while saving to my MySql database the big base64 string is chopped and kind of becomes useless to again form the image.

Comment: Have you tried changing the type of Image.Base64 to a string and convert it manually using Encoding?

Comment: Originally it was string but then while saving it to my MySql database it was chopping the big base64 string midway, so someone suggested me to use byte[] instead.

Comment: @MartinKlinke I found this (https://adrientorris.github.io/aspnet-core/manage-base64-encoding.html) perhaps could you kindly point out exactly where and how will I use this function in my code? My model, controller and repository is there in my question

Comment: Maybe this is of any help to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34654184/unable-to-deserialize-an-object-with-a-byte-array-property-using-json-net-8-0-1

Comment: If you can't manage to get the automatic conversion to work, you could still do it by hand. Either way, you might want to separate between the type that defines your API payload and the internal model for storage and processing. If you had this separation, you could do the mapping and conversion as needed. If you don't want this separation, you would probably need two properties, one for deserialization and one (maybe just a getter that converts on demand) for access to the byte array. HTH